# How to send an e-mail with image atachment using celery and dajngo?

Tags: python, django, celery

I want to use celery for sending an e-mail with photo, but I am getting the "Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable" error. I just don't understand how to properly do it. As far as I see, celery doesn't support bytes. But I tried to convert it to string and get other error.

**views.py**

```
from main_app.tasks import send_creator_submission_email_task


class BecomeCreatorView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'become_creator.html'
    become_creator_form = BecomeCreatorForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.become_creator_form()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.become_creator_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            photo = form.cleaned_data['photo']
            send_creator_submission_email_task.delay(self.kwargs.get('slug'), photo.file, photo.name)
            messages.success(request, "Thank you!")
            return redirect(self.success_url)
        messages.error(request, "Error!")
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

**tasks.py**

```
@shared_task
def send_creator_submission_email_task(slug, image_file, image_filename):
    return send_creator_submission_email(slug, image_file, image_filename)
```

**email.py**

```
def send_creator_submission_email(slug, image_file, image_filename):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, slug=slug)
    current_site = Site.objects.get_current().domain

    email_context = {
        'current_site': current_site,
        'user_email': user.email,
        'user_slug': user.slug,
        'approve_url': f"http://{current_site}{reverse_lazy('approve_user', kwargs={'slug': user.slug})}",
        "decline_url": f"http://{current_site}{reverse_lazy('decline_user', kwargs={'slug': user.slug})}"
    }

    html_message = render_to_string('email/admin_decision_email.html', email_context)
    plain_message = strip_tags(html_message)

    email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject="New creator submission",
        body=plain_message,
        from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
        to=[settings.EMAIL_ADMIN],
    )

    email.attach_alternative(html_message, "text/html")
    email.attach(image_filename, image_file.read())
    email.send()
```

If you want to recreate the case, these files are for you:
**forms.py**

```
class BecomeCreatorForm(forms.Form):
    photo = forms.ImageField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.ClearableFileInput
    )
```

**admin_decision_email.html**

```
{% autoescape off %}

<p>New user photo submission from: {{ user_email }}</p>
<p>User slug: {{ user_slug }}</p>
<p>Please approve or decline the attached photo.</p>

<p>Actevate: {{ approve_url }}</p>
<p>Decline: {{ decline_url }}</p>

{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: Celery put your task as a JSON object to your queue handler. That's why I suggest to temporarily saving the object and removing it later if not needed.

Comment: @Marco, Thank you for a reply! How I suppose to do it? Somehow save image like a temp file and pass it to the celery?

Comment: Save the file and pass the path to the celery function. Then in the celery function, you will open the file and process it with the rest of the function.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've handled it by myself. I'll leave answer for descendants.

```
import base64
```

Encode the image in view and pass it to the celery function.

```
if form.is_valid():
    photo_data = form.cleaned_data['photo'].read()
    photo_name = form.cleaned_data['photo'].name
    photo_data_base64 = base64.b64encode(photo_data).decode()
    send_creator_submission_email_task.delay(self.kwargs.get('slug'), photo_data_base64, photo_name)
    messages.success(request, "Thank you!")
    return redirect(self.success_url)
```

Decode it in the celery function and attach to the e-mail:

```
photo_data = base64.b64decode(attachment_data)
email.attach(attachment_name, photo_data)
```

Thats it!